# ImportError: cannot import name 'YOLO' from 'ultralytics' (unknown location)

Tags: python, deep-learning, importerror, yolo, yolov8

I am trying to build a YOLOv8 model, and I have built it using cloning github repo of YOLOv8.
https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics

For training the yolov8 docs say that I need to start as follows

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
```

But when I try to do the same after using pip install ultralytics, I get this error:

```
ImportError                   Traceback (most recent call last)

/tmp/ipykernel_28/546599741.py in <module>
----> 1 from ultralytics import YOLO
      2 
      3 # Load a model
      4 model = YOLO('yolov8n.yaml')  # build a new model from YAML
      5 model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)

ImportError: cannot import name 'YOLO' from 'ultralytics' (unknown location)
```

Comment: it seems to not recognize that you have ultralytics installed. are you sure you're in the right env?

Comment: Apparently this is an issue. Cloning in installing ultralytics seems to be a hassle. I did the same steps you have followed since my torch dependencies are a bit different I don't want to use pip install ultralytics. I will update this with an answer when I solve it

Comment: Umm no I was wrong LOL. It works just fine by clonign the repo I guess you are not in the same repo as others said. If you directly clone from ultralytics from the repo though, as I have noticed, you get ultralytics directory and isnide that directory there is another ultralytics directory so your issue should be solved by from ultralytics.ultralytics import YOLO

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check whether the package is installed:

```
pip show ultralytics
```

If it is installed, you have next to check the package compatibility based on what you have. For instance, you may need to use a specific version that ensures that YOLO is installed or compatible.

```
pip install ultralytics==1.0.1
```

Check and make sure that YOLO imports are in the imported ultralytics package.

If none of the above helped, you may additionally make sure you have all the necessary dependencies satisfied for the YOLOv8 model.