get predicted class name in YOLOv8
i want to get class data in my python script,
i test this code but i have a problem :

from ultralytics.yolo.engine.model import YOLO

model = YOLO("path/to/best.pt")
results = model.predict(source=0, save=True, conf=0.5, show=True)
names = model.names

for r in results:
for c in r.boxes.cls:
print(names[int(c)])


**output:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:....project\\2.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from ultralytics.yolo.engine.model import YOLO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ultralytics.yolo'


Did you install it?

Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196856/17233687 that seems to provide a solution:
Check if you have installed ultralytics using :
pip show ultralytics

or :
pip list

If not installed, proceed to install using :
pip install ultralytics

For a specific version :
pip install ultralytics==X.X.X


I have tried: pip install --upgrade ultralytics, and my version is 8.2.2.
but the problems remaines

Then, try replacing by the following : from ultralytics import YOLO.
Also, check on how to use the package here : https://docs.ultralytics.com/quickstart/#use-ultralytics-with-python.
Finally, I think you haven't mentioned a correct path in model = YOLO("path/to/best.pt")
